# SpaceChem: Why can't I advance to the next level?

Tags: spacechem

I recently beat a level in SpaceChem (I feel like I need a cigarette after I beat one - and I don't smoke!) and I was met with the following unpleasantness:

[image: SpaceChem screenshot]

Why can't I select the next level? Did I forget to do something in the prior one? Is this a bug?

Comment: It appears as though you did unlock a level - Molecular Foundry. Perhaps you've been ignoring it so far and the game now requires you to do it before proceeding? I know I haven't unlocked that world yet.

Comment: The Molecular Foundry was unlocked at the start of the world; I'm working on it now in the hopes it'll unlock the rest of it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to solve Molecular Foundry first. I hit the same thing. That level is hard.

The level you can't get to in the far right there is actually the last level on the planet.